# Tool for JSON schema validation

Tags: json, spring, maven

I have need to validate incoming POST jsons in my project. This is a part of a RESTFul json service i am developing. These jsons need to be validated for

1. mandatory attributes
2. invalid attributes
3. data types

Just read about [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/wiki) and it looks good.

Has anyone used this in  maven/spring projects? Is there any better (ito - API, stability) tool that i can use?

Update - i am also looking at [json tools](http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=6644)

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: author of https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator here...

This library has no dependency on anything web-related, so you can use it in a bare-bones Java application, a servlet-only Java application (I have even [made one](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/)) or with Spring. It won't be a problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the http://code.google.com/p/jsonschema/. This might solve your issue.

Also refer [JSON schema validation using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499126/json-schema-validation-using-java)