# JSON duplicate key, validate using java(spring)

Tags: java, json, validation, duplicates

```
[
    {
    "id" : "Unique_Id25",
    "firstName" : "Test Name",
    "firstName" : "Test Name 2",
    }
]
```

Above I have an example of a duplicate key, `firstName`. I use Postman and it warns that a duplicate key exists, but the POST request passes as I don't currently validate for it.

So I'm asking if there's a cool java/spring way of checking for this duplicate and throwing an exception.

Otherwise I'll try to build these JSON keys into an array and looping through.

Comment: Related: [How do I validate incoming JSON data inside a REST service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154983/how-do-i-validate-incoming-json-data-inside-a-rest-service)

Comment: I've been using http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/ to test but no success are validating duplicate key elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper;
```

Use ObjectMapper to enable duplicate detection

```
jsonObjectMapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
```