# Validate input before Jackson in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, hibernate-validator

I've built a REST endpoint using Spring Boot. `JSON` is posted to the endpoint. Jackson converts the `JSON` giving me an object.

The `JSON` look like this:

```
{
    "parameterDateUnadjusted": "2017-01-01",
    "parameterDateAdjusted": "2017-01-02"
}
```

Jackson converts the `JSON` to an object based on this class:

```
public class ParameterDate {

    @NotNull(message = "Parameter Date Unadjusted can not be blank or null")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date parameterDateUnadjusted;
    @NotNull(message = "Parameter Date Adjusted can not be blank or null")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date parameterDateAdjusted;
    private Date parameterDateAdded;
    private Date parameterDateChanged;
}
```

This all works fine. The issue I'm having is that I would like to validate the data before Jackson converts the data. For instance if I post

```
{
    "parameterDateUnadjusted": "2017-01-01",
    "parameterDateAdjusted": "2017-01-40"
}
```

Where `parameterDateAdjusted` is not a valid date (there is no month with 40 days in it). Jackson converts this to `2017-02-09`. One way of getting around this is to have a class that is only strings let's call it `ParameterDateInput`. Validate each filed with Hibernate Validator in the `parameterDateInput` object and then copy the `parameterDateInput` object to `parameterDate` where each field has the correct type (dates are of type `Date` and not of type `String`). This to me doesn't look like a very elegant solution. Is there some other way I can solve this? How is data generally validated in Spring Boot when posted as `JSON`? I like to be able to send back a message to the user/client what is wrong with the data that is being posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I validate incoming JSON data inside a REST service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154983/how-do-i-validate-incoming-json-data-inside-a-rest-service)

Answer (score 1):

How about a custom JSON deserializer where you can write down the logic you want:

```
@RestController
public class JacksonCustomDesRestEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/yourEndPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object createRole(@RequestBody ParameterDate paramDate) {
        return paramDate;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = RoleDeserializer.class)
public class ParameterDate {
    // ......
}

public class RoleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ParameterDate> {
    @Override
    public ParameterDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        String parameterDateUnadjusted = node.get("parameterDateUnadjusted").getTextValue();
        //Do what you want with the date and set it to object from type ParameterDate and return the object at the end. 
        //Don't forget to fill all the properties to this object because you do not want to lose data that came from the request.
        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example of what the contents of the `deserialize` method would look like?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check the dates. `setLenient()` method

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate, String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
      dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Just define own annotation to validate the value

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyDateFormatCheckValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface MyDateFormatCheck {
    String pattern();
...
```

and the validator class

```
public class MyDateFormatCheckValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyDateFormatCheck, String> {

    private MyDateFormatCheck check; 
    @Override
    public void initialize(MyDateFormatCheck constraintAnnotation) {
        this.check= constraintAnnotation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        if ( object == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        return isValidDate(object, check.pattern());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've create an interface called MyDateFormatCheck and a class called MyDateFormatCheckValidator that implements the interface. In the class I put the isValidDate method. The I annotated my fields like @MyDateFormatCheck(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", message = "Not matching")
    private Date parameterDateUnadjusted;
@MyDateFormatCheck(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", message = "Not matching")
    private Date parameterDateAdjusted;. I added message since it gave me an error. Now I get another error MyDateFormatCheck contains Constraint annotation, but does not contain a groups parameter.".

Comment: Mostly this way but MyDateFormatCheckValidator does not implement the interface but ConstraintValidator instead. See the example http://www.journaldev.com/3626/hibernate-validator-jsr303-example-tutorial

Comment: I sort of got this working but I needed to change the field type for `parameterDateUadjusted` and `parameterDateAdjusted` to String which is not what I want since I want Jackson to convert the `JSON` values to data of type `Date`.

Comment: Validate can happen only **after** converting but if the sent date has wrong format instead of validation message you have converter exception (you can try old way and pass e.g `abc` rather than date). I see no good solution for the problem except using strings. You can add getter/setter which converts the string to Date on fly.