# java/jersey/jackson - validate input JSON

Tags: java, json, validation, jersey, jackson

I am writing a REST API with a Java/Jersey/Jackson stack. All JSON parsing and generating is done with Jackson. The REST layer is handled by Jersey. It will be embedded in a Grizzly container.

In my API, I accept JSON in my endpoints. For example:

```
@POST
public Response post(final SomeObject input) {
    return ...;
}
```

What is the best way to validate the `input`? There are certain things I would like to validate:

- `input` must be not null
- certain fields of `input` must be not null
- certain fields of `input` must follow a regular expression (text fields)
- certain fields of `input` must be in a range (numeric fields)
- ...

If possible, I would like to change my code as less as possible. That is, I prefer to annotate my classes, methods and parameters to integrate the validation.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html

Comment: Json validator may be helpful to you. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499126/json-schema-validation-using-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also [BeanValidationApi](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) (javax.validation.constraints) and then annotate your fields with `@NotNull,@Pattern`, etc. Jersey also provides [Bean Validation Support](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org).

And since you use Jackson, you can use [my library](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) which does exactly that.

However this means you'd need to change your logic so that you receive the JSON (as a `JsonNode`) instead of the serialized POJO, and only then serialize to your POJO.